# Connect SMB share in Windows 10

Tags: windows-10, samba

I cannot connect my SMB shares on Windows 10. I get the same error on 2 machines, both fresh installs.

[Windows 10 Error Dialogue](https://i.stack.imgur.com/oNnBx.png)

**Android and Windows 7 can connect just fine.** Workgroup is correct. Sambauser has a username and password set on the server.

I tried:

- Adding "AllowInsecureGuestAuth" key to
  \HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SYSTEM\CurrentControlSet\Services\LanmanWorkstation\Parameters
- Adding "server max protocol=SMB3" to smb.conf on the server
- Connecting with the ip like this "\\192.168.0.55\share"
- Disabling Network Adapter Power Saving
- Start Windows 10 in Diagnostic Mode
- Disable SMB2/3 in Windows, enable SMB1
  https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/help/2696547/how-to-enable-and-disable-smbv1,-smbv2,-and-smbv3-in-windows-vista,-windows-server-2008,-windows-7,-windows-server-2008-r2,-windows-8,-and-windows-server-2012

At random the network drive connects. I can browse my files for 10 seconds or so. Then it drops dead again.

Answer (score -1):

On the Windows PC, change `HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SYSTEM\CurrentControlSet\Control\Lsa\LmCompatibilityLevel` to 4.

Network security: LAN Manager authentication level is usually set to "Send LM & NTLM - use NTLMv2 session security if negotiated" by Group policies for backup compatibility with older clients.

Changing LmCompatibilityLevel to 4 sets it to "Send NTLMv2 response only".