# Windows 10 Edu SMB Share not available

Tags: windows-10, networking, debian, network-shares, samba

I have created a SMB share on a small debian server. I can connect to it via a notebook(with debian), a notebook (with Win10 Pro) and i also tested it with a app on my smartphone. Everything works fine. Just my pc (Win10 Edu) cant find the SMB share. A virtual machine running on the pc also can't find the SMB-share.
Net view  returns code 53.
I have tried multiple things if read in forums, but nothing helped so far. Hope you can help me!

**EDIT1**

The output of testparm -s -v | grep protocol is:

```
client ipc max protocol = default
client ipc min protocol = default
client max protocol = default
client min protocol = CORE
server max protocol = SMB3
server min protocol = SMB2
```

i set in the smb.conf in the [global part]:

```
max protocol: SMB3 
min protocol: SMB2
```

**EDIT2**

I just tried it with three additional computers:

Two with Win10 Edu -> Can't find/access SMB-share

One with Win10 Pro -> Works fine
So i guess it must be some kind of problem with the Win10 EDU-Version.

**EDIT3**

I tried gpedit.msc:

Computer Configuration\Administrative Templates\Network\LanmanWorkstation
and set insecure guest logon to enable.

Restarted the computer

-> Also doesn't work

then i uncommented the line in /etc/samba/smb.conf

`#map to guest = Bad User`

-> Connection WORKED!!

Nextstep:

Activate map to guest = Bad User
Check GPEDIT -> insecure guest logon STILL ENABLED

-> Connection doesn't work

So checking regedit:
Windows Regsitry:

HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE -> SYSTEM -> CurrentControlSet -> Services -> LanmanWorkstation -> Parameters

AllowInsecureGuestAuth set it to 1

Restarted the computer
-> Connection WORKED!!

So i guess the problem is **solved** :) Hope this Thread may help other users!
Find the solution on

[Windows 10 and Server 2016 clients block access to (Samba) shares with public guest account: Technical analysis and workaround for event 31017](https://www.claudiokuenzler.com/blog/879/windows-10-server-2016-access-samba-share-guest-account-analysis-workaround-event-31017)

Comment: What version of SMB is the share configured to use? Edit your question instead of submitting a comment

Comment: Does [this](https://superuser.com/questions/1522896/windows-10-cannot-connect-to-linux-samba-shares-except-from-smb1-cifs?rq=1) help or [this](https://superuser.com/questions/1201843/connect-smb-share-in-windows-10?rq=1)